# Bluetooth status history on Mac

Tags: macos, bluetooth, macos-catalina

Is there a log somewhere which shows the Bluetooth history on a Mac?

For example, when you toggle Bluetooth on/off is this kept in a log somewhere?

I use a 2017 MacBook Pro running on Catalina 10.15.3

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mojave so this might not work for you, but it is worth a try.

I have an *Apple binary property list* file located at

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
```

I converted it to xml like so

```
sudo plutil -convert binary1 /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
```

You can convert it back with

```
sudo plutil -convert binary1 /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
```

If you don't have that file, it might be located in one of these, hopefully

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.BluetoothAudioAgent.plis
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.BluetoothFileExchange.plist
```

Comment: I realised that you wanted the time of toggling the actual bluetooth on/off and not when devices where connected. Sorry about that, maybe this is of some help to you or someone else anyhow.